# How to close aberrant tooltips in Windows

Tags: windows, tooltip

So, here I am, trying to watch The Cleveland Show (TM).

[image]

[image]

And, as happens from time to time, some program or another has left a modal tooltip.

I don't know which program; how can I lose the tooltip, short of logoff/reboot?

Currently happening on Windows 10, but I have seen it on other versions.

Comment: Have you tried showing desktop and then switching back to your show?

Comment: We have a winner !!!  D'oh! For years, that never occurred to me! Post your answer and I shall reward it. Thanx a 1,000,000

Comment: Answer written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### how can I lose the (errant) tooltip, short of logoff/reboot?

You can minimise all apps by [showing the desktop](https://easykey.uk/windows/3-quick-ways-to-show-the-desktop) and then switching back to your show.

This should clear any errant tooltips.

Comment: `Windows key + D` to hide all programs/show desktop, then again to reverse does the trick!  This has plagued my for years. Every time I rebooted. Never knew it was so simple.